# How to implemment a lock and release to mysql table?

Tags: mysql, perl

I have a perl file test.pl that  read a  mysql  table  t1 and do some operations.

If two users execute test.pl at same time, then i need to block one user from read and write to t1 .

Once the other user completes his operations in t1, then allow other user starts his operations in t1

How can i achieve this.?

Can we use 'Lock' of mysql.?

Or any other solutions

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LOCK TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html) to explicitly lock a table.

However, you may want to look into using a [transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html), to keep data consistent while running `test.pl`, but not completely lock other processes from using the database.

How exactly this works depends on the database engine you're using, so you should also read the section on [Transactions and Atomic Operations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html)